# Eigenvalues of (Diagonal + PDxPSD)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Given $D, P, L \in \mathbb{S}^n$ such that $D$ is a diagonal matrix $D \succ 0$, $P \succ 0$, and $L \succeq 0$, then $(D + PL)$ is a non-singular matrix with strictly positive eigenvalues.

My attempt to prove the above is as follows:

We define the matrix $Z =  dI +PL$ where $d = \lambda_\mathrm{min} (D)$. The eigenvalues of $Z$ are $\lambda_i(Z) = d + \lambda_i(PL)$ for $i = 1, ..., n$. We know that $\lambda_\mathrm{min}(PL) = 0$, hence $\lambda_\mathrm{min}(Z) = d >0$. Since $\lambda_\mathrm{min}(D+PL) \geq \lambda_\mathrm{min}(Z)$, then $\lambda_\mathrm{min} (D + PL) >0$ and $\mathrm{det}(D+PL) \neq 0$ which completes the proof.

My intuition is that $\lambda_\mathrm{min}(D+PL) \geq \lambda_\mathrm{min}(Z)$ should hold as we are studying the "smallest possible sum". Does this seem logical?

Comment: if you are going to write things like $\lambda_\mathrm{min}(D+PL) \geq \lambda_\mathrm{min}(Z)$ then you need to first justify your implicit assertion that $D+PL$ has purely real spectra

Comment: If $D$ and $P$ are diagonal matrices and $L$ is a laplacian of a connected graph, does that verify the implicit assertion?

Comment: why does the original post only mention that $D$ is diagonal and not $P$?  If they are both diagonal then consider the similar matrix $P^\frac{-1}{2}(D + PL)P^\frac{1}{2} = D +P^\frac{1}{2}LP^\frac{1}{2}$ which is a sum of 2 real symmetric PSD matrices where $D$ is PD hence the sum is real symmetric PD and all eigenvalues are positive-- this gives the desired eigenvalue result for the original matrix via similarity.